# Common action filter or HttpModule for asp.net MVC web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, httpmodule, action-filter

We have a web service written in MVC 1.0. There is a need to intercept every request being made to this service. In this case is it wise to develop a HTTPModule which intercepts every request and modifies the method parameter before it reached the code or should I create action filter and place the attribute on every method ? My first guess is rather then marking every method with action filter attribute, I should just create a httpModule , this will minimize the effort and code.

Example

> 1. Client calls the "servicename/action/username"
> 2. Server intercept this request in HTTPModule , decodes the username
> 3. Decode username is passed to the Action.

Do you guys have any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by using a custom route, inheriting from Route. Something like:

```
public class UserNameRoute : Route
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        // Not sure if you need to set routeData.Values["username"] too
        // to make sure the route catches on
        routeData.DataTokens["username"] = DecodeUserName(routeData.Values);

        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values) {

        values["username"] = EncodeUserName(requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens);

        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}
```

Then you "just" have to implement DecodeUserName and EncodeUserName.

Comment: Interesting....so does this gets called on any request being made to the web service

i.e. //service/username
     //service/username/address

Comment: If you create this route and add it to the RouteTable, like any other route, it'll get evaluated, yeah. The MVC framework uses the GetRouteData to decide whether the route matches (return value is not null), so it gives you a chance to do some other stuff along the way. Note that by inserting this as a route before others, you can also influence the other routes by manipulating the route data on httpContext. I don't advise that though, because it can make route behavour obscure and unpredictable.